# настройка путей в tsconfig

Tags: javascript, angular

Хочу настроить `tsconfig` для того, чтобы можно было бы компонентам angular получать доступ к моделям и провайдеру данных, которые находятся в отличном от их каталога пути. Я не смог узнать, можно ли в `import` каким-либо образом указать на обращение к родительскому каталогу, однако нашел, что внутри `tsconfig.json` можно включить параметр `paths`, который я настроил следующим образом:

```
"baseUrl": "./",
"paths": {
   "@facultygroup/*": [ "src/app/groups/*" ],
   "@dataservice": [ "src/app/app.dataservice.ts" ],
   "@appstyle": [ "src/app/app.component.style.css" ]
}
```

Однако когда я попытался включить `dataservice` в свой typescript-файл с помощью:

```
import { DataService } from '@dataservice';
```

мне выдало ошибку, что модуль `@dataservice` не найден. Можете пожалуйста подсказать, каким образом в таком случае работает такое подключение и работает ли вообще?

Answer (score 0):

у меня в проекте вот так :

```
"paths": {
            "@app/*": ["src/app/*"],
            "@mocks/*": ["src/mocks/*"],
            "@scss/*": ["src/scss/*"],
            "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
            "@environments/*": ["src/environments/*"],

            "@core/*": ["src/app/core/*"],
            "@modules/*": ["src/app/modules/*"],
            "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"],
            "@types/*": ["src/app/core/types/*"],

        }
```

но я б тебе посоветовал зделать штото вроде `@services : [".../app/core/services/*"]`